# Inserting Php code inside html tag by php

Tags: php

In my html/php file I have the following  tag:

```
<select name="seitJ">
    <option value=20 <?php if ( $_GET["bisJ"]==20 ) echo("selected"); ?> >2020</option>
    <option value=19 <?php if ( $_GET["bisJ"]==19 ) echo("selected"); ?> >2019</option>             
    <option value=18 <?php if ( $_GET["bisJ"]==18 ) echo("selected"); ?> >2018</option>
</select>
```

What I want is a php code which updates this code every beginning of a new year automatically. My problem are NOT the date- functions but how to insert the php code contained in the  tags. I think I would have to include php code inside php code which I know doesn’t work.

Comment: Haven't got a clue what you want to do.

Comment: @MarkOverton He wants to add every new year a new line in his select (in 2021, he wants 18, 19, 20 and 21 for options). Can be done by looking at the current year and looping from 18 to last 2 digits of current year.

Comment: Can I generate this piece of code by means of php?

Comment: @Pierre That’s correct.

Comment: If PHP can't generate dynamic code, I'm wondering what it's useful to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This should do what you want:

Essentially I am setting the year to the current year (2020), setting the target year to the current year minus 4 years (2016) and I am looping through, reducing the year by 1 each iteration until we reach our target year.

```
<select name="seitJ">
    <?php
    $year = date('Y');
    $target = $year - 4;

    for($i = $year; $i > $target; $i--) {
        $digits = substr($i, 2);
        $selected = ($_GET['bisJ'] == $digits ? 'selected' : '');
        echo '<option value="' . $digits . '" ' . $selected . '>' . $i . '</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

---

### Resources:

[substr()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

[for()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)

Comment: This does not work.

Comment: I’ve tested it, it works, what result are you getting.

Comment: Sorry, my fault! Your code works perfectly. Thanks very much.

Comment: All good! If you could mark this answer as correct it would be appreciated

Comment: Closer inspection shows that the code does not do what it should do. It does not transfer the information which entry entry of the list had been choosen. Try the test code:

Comment: That'll be a separate issue - if you create a question with details on what you're trying to achieve I can take a look.

Comment: Ups- everything's ok ...

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
<select name="seitJ">
<?php 
   for($i = 2000; $i < date('Y'); $i++){
      echo "<option value=<?php echo $i; (date('Y') == $i) ? echo selected : ''?> >$i</option>";
   }
?>
</select>
```

The date('Y') will get you the current year so it will update automaticly.
And keep in mind that it's a good practice to create a loop instead of writing the values one by one.